# Modify content of php://input

Tags: php, unit-testing

I need to make an auto-test for a function, which grabs request body with

`file_get_contents('php://input')`

So, I run my test in command-line, and want to put something in "request body", like

`file_put_contents('php://input', 'kek')`

But this straightforward approach is not working.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: You didn't tell us the environment, how do you make a manual-test?

Comment: php://input is a read-only stream that allows you to read raw data from the request body. php://input is not available with enctype="multipart/form-data".

Comment: @shingo I've mentioned: it runs from command line. It's functional test with Codeception. Creating application class, simulating web server behaviour.

Comment: You can only read from this stream. php://input contains the HTTP request data, try doing that.

Comment: Does this help perhaps? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38197116/how-do-i-simulate-php-input-in-php

Comment: Apparently it's time to refactor this code and decouple the business logic from the input device ;)